# Proving sequence is decreasing by using its associated real function

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, monotone-functions

We are required to prove that a given sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotonically decreasing, i.e. $a_{n+1}<a_n$,  for almost all n. Let's say there is a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $a_n = f(n)$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is it then possible that, taking the right assumptions, we can state that $f'(x) < 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \implies a_{n+1}<a_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

What I immediately see is that the function $f(x)$ must be differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb{N}.$ Then if this was the case, and if we were to find a derivative using standard rules of differentiation, we should be fine?

Is what I am imagining possible? If not, what facts are holding us back? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: In the statement $a_{n+1}<a_n \iff f'(x)<0$, how is $x$ related to $n$?

Comment: @AlanAbraham I've edited the question now

Comment: The forward implication does not hold true. What the function does at points $n \in \mathbb N$ does not and cannot determine what the function does at all $x \in \mathbb R$.  You could easily construct a counterexample using the same idea as in the recent answer to your previous question.

Comment: @dxiv I am trying to prove that a sequence is decreasing because the function is. But if the function was decreasing at interval $[a,+\infty), a\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $f'(x)<0$, how doesn't that imply that it also decreases if we are looking at it for only natural values of x.

Comment: You could be lucky and find a nice function $f(n)$ that satisfies your requirements, $a_n = f(n)$ and the real function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is increasing for $x\gt 0$ (possibly by virtue of a positive derivative there).

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav That's the reverse implication, which is true. But in the question you wrote it as an equivalence, which is not.

Comment: @dxiv Now I've got it. but can we prove the backward implication?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav If you only assume $f'(x) \lt 0$ for $x \in \mathbb N$ then that's not enough to prove $a_{n+1} \lt a_n$ either. Assuming $f$ strictly decreasing is, however, sufficient.

Comment: Maybe my question is not stated as clearly as it should be. So you are saying that it should be differentiable for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$, in order to prove that it is strictly decreasing? @dxiv

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav No, I am not saying any such thing. For the same sequence $a_n$ there exist infinitely many functions $f(x)$ such that $a_n=f(n)$, and there is no relationship between the monotonicity of $a_n$ and the signs of $f'(n)$. So it doesn't make sense to say that the function "*should*" be one way or another.

Comment: I assumed that since $f'(x)$ tells us about monotonicity of $f(x)$ we could maybe abuse it and infer something about monotonicity of $a_n$ since the mapping $a_n: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is just a subset of $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, since we know had $a_n = f(n)$ @dxiv

Comment: Now that I think of this more, we would probably need to take  f''(x) into question to find out if the function decreases monotonically. Namely $f''(x) >0$ and $f'(x) < 0$ should maybe suffice?

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav Sorry, but it is still not clear what you are asking. The sign of $f'$ at the discrete set of points $n \in \mathbb N$ tells nothing about the monotonicity of $f$ overall. From the same answer referenced before, take for example $f_1(x)=\sin 2\pi x$ then $f_1'(n) \gt 0$, or $f_2(x)=- \sin 2\pi x$ then $f_2'(n) \lt 0$. But both $f_1$ and $f_2$ correspond to the same constant sequence $a_n=0=f_1(n)=f_2(n)$ even though their derivatives have opposite signs at each $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I am really bad at thinking of any counterexamples, at all times.That's probably why I get stuck at relatively simples ideas as this one seems to be. Now that you have pointed out those examples, It's obvious that there are flaws in my logic. 
But just to get this straight 100%. I would want to check whether $f'(x) < 0$ for all values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$, in some inverval $[a,+\infty), a\in \mathbb{N}$. If this is the case, how does it not imply that $a_n$ is also decreasing at this interval for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$
I see why we don't understand each other and will edit the question @dxiv

Comment: @ĐumićBranislav This last implication is true, but kind of trivial. It simply means that $n+1 \gt n$ $\implies f(n+1) \lt f(n)$ because $f$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: Wow it took as a while to untangle that... Would laugh but I am too tired. It's not trivial for me as I have a little formal training in proofs. Please look and the edited question.